# Get explanations with OWL API + Pellet

Tags: owl, protege, owl-api, pellet, reasoner

I am trying to get the explanations for inferences (like in Protégé) using OWL API and Pellet Reasoner. But I am stuck with the OWLAxiom. Maybe someone knows how to get the inferences.

[image]
[image]

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Set;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.*;
import com.clarkparsia.owlapi.explanation.PelletExplanation;
import com.clarkparsia.owlapi.explanation.io.manchester.ManchesterSyntaxExplanationRenderer;
import com.clarkparsia.owlapiv3.OWL;
import com.clarkparsia.pellet.owlapiv3.PelletReasoner;
import com.clarkparsia.pellet.owlapiv3.PelletReasonerFactory;

public class Main {

    private static final String file = "file:/folder/ontology.owl";
    private static final String NS = "http://www.semanticweb.org/oliver/ontologies/ontology.owl#";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws OWLOntologyCreationException, OWLException, IOException {
        PelletExplanation.setup();

        ManchesterSyntaxExplanationRenderer renderer = new ManchesterSyntaxExplanationRenderer();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        renderer.startRendering(out);

        OWLOntologyManager manager = OWL.manager;
        OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntology(IRI.create(file));

        PelletReasoner reasoner = PelletReasonerFactory.getInstance().createReasoner(ontology);

        PelletExplanation expGen = new PelletExplanation(reasoner);

        OWLIndividual angle = OWL.Individual(NS + "angle_C");
        OWLDataProperty hasAngle = OWL.DataProperty(NS + "has_angle_of");

        OWLAxiom axiom; // I don't understand what should be here

        Set<Set<OWLAxiom>> explanations = expGen.getEntailmentExplanations(axiom); // is .getEntailmentExplanations the right method? 
        out.println("Why " + angle + " " + hasAngle + " - ");

        renderer.render(explanations);
        renderer.endRendering();
    }
}
```

Comment: The axiom is for what you want to get the explanations. In your case on your screenshot you have chosen a particular data property assertion `has_angle_of 105` - and this one holds for a particular individual. In your code you already have the OWL entities for the individual and the data property. All you have to do is to use an `OWLDataFactory` which you can get from the `OWLOntologyManager` object via `getOWLDataFactory()` method. This data factory `df` can be used to create the axiom you need. Call `df.getOWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom(angle, hasAngle, 105)`.

Comment: also, Javadoc is [here](https://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_5/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/providers/DataAssertionProvider.html#getOWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom-org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDataPropertyExpression-org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLIndividual-int-) - for other axioms, use the data factory as well.

Comment: @UninformedUser thank you for explaining. But now I am getting: "Explanation: AXIOM IS NOT ENTAILED!". Do you know what could go wrong? `OWLAxiom axiom = dataFactory.getOWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom(hasAngle, angle, 105);`

Comment: The error means that axiom is not actually entailed by the ontology - make sure that namespaces match between the ontology and your code, and that the datatype for 105 also matches. Should be xsd:integer from what I can see.

Comment: @Ignazio thank you for the answer. While I was trying to fix this, I've bumped into another problem: `"Explanation contains removed axiom"`. Any ideas what's went wrong?

Comment: The `removed axiom` is the SWRL rule that is shown last in the Protégé explanation pic.

Comment: Not a clue, without being able to debug this locally. Can you share the ontology? This code is based on OWLAPI version 3, which has been out of active use for years. Protégé is using version 4.

Comment: @Ignazio sure! Take a look at the .owl and .java files. Thanks! [repo](https://github.com/olehsmysh/ont/tree/main)