# Get explanations with OWL API + Openllet

Tags: owl, protege, owl-api, swrl, pellet

I am trying to get the explanations for inferences (like in Protégé with Pellet) using OWL API and Openllet Reasoner. (Previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78036788/get-explanations-with-owl-api-pellet), I used OWL API + Pellet, but @Ignazio suggested to use newer version of OWL API, so I wrote new code using OWL API 5.5.0 and Openllet 2.6.5 - `Maven: com.github.galigator.openllet:openllet-examples:2.6.5`)

[image]

[image]

But I am receiving `Exception in thread "main" org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLRuntimeException: Explanation contains removed axiom:...`

As you can see in Explanation pic, the exception appears because of this SWRL rule:

`new:Triangle(?t) ^ new:angle_c(?t, ?c) ^ new:angle_b(?t, ?b) ^ new:angle_a(?t, ?a) ^ new:has_angle_of(?a, ?v1) ^ new:has_angle_of(?b, ?v2) ^ swrlb:add(?v3, ?v1, ?v2) ^ swrlb:subtract(?v4, 180, ?v3) -> new:has_angle_of(?c, ?v4)`

This is my code:

```
package org.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Set;

import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.*;
import openllet.owlapi.OpenlletReasoner;
import openllet.owlapi.OpenlletReasonerFactory;
import openllet.owlapi.explanation.PelletExplanation;
import openllet.owlapi.explanation.io.manchester.ManchesterSyntaxExplanationRenderer;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;

public class Main {
    private static final String file = "file:/folder/new.owl";
    private static final String NS = "http://www.semanticweb.org/oliver/ontologies/new.owl#";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws OWLOntologyCreationException, OWLException, IOException {
        OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
        OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntology(IRI.create(file));
        OWLDataFactory dataFactory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();

        OpenlletReasoner reasoner = OpenlletReasonerFactory.getInstance().createReasoner(ontology);
        PelletExplanation explanationGenerator = new PelletExplanation(reasoner);

        ManchesterSyntaxExplanationRenderer renderer = new ManchesterSyntaxExplanationRenderer();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        renderer.startRendering(out);

        OWLIndividual angle = dataFactory.getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create(NS + "angle_C"));
        OWLDataPropertyExpression hasAngle = dataFactory.getOWLDataProperty(IRI.create(NS + "has_angle_of"));

        OWLAxiom axiom = dataFactory.getOWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom(hasAngle, angle, 105);
        System.out.println(axiom);
        System.out.println(ontology.getAxioms(AxiomType.SWRL_RULE));

        Set<Set<OWLAxiom>> explanations = explanationGenerator.getEntailmentExplanations(axiom);

        renderer.render(explanations);
        renderer.endRendering();
    }
}
```

Maybe someone has an idea, why both OWL API with Pellet and OWL API with Openllet are showing this exception? Files like ontology, owlapi+pellet and owlapi+openllet are [here](https://github.com/olehsmysh/ont).